# GetAsync : not returning HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, webapi2, httpresponsemessage

The apps should receive **httpresponsemessage** from **LoginUser()** but it becomes not responding.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoginUser(tUser.Text, Password.Text).Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Notifier.Notify("Successfully logged in.. Please wait!");

        }
        else
        {
            Notifier.Notify("Please check your Credential..");
        }            
    }
```

---

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> LoginUser(string userid, string password)
    {
        string URI = "http://api.danubeco.com/api/userapps/authenticate";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("c291cmF2OmtheWFs");

            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", URI, userid, password)))
            {
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Please help!

Comment: Remove all the async stuff and make sure it works.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient

Comment: Is it a UI app? If so, than you are causing a deadlock on `LoginUser( ... ).Result.IsSuccessStatusCode`. Read more here - http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread and causing a deadlock. [From Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (Just replace `GetJsonAsync` with your `LoginUser` method, and `GetStringAsync` with `client.GetAsync`):

> So this is what happens, starting with the top-level method
>   (Button1_Click for UI / MyController.Get for ASP.NET):
>
> 1. The top-level method calls GetJsonAsync (within the UI/ASP.NET context).
> 2. GetJsonAsync starts the REST request by calling HttpClient.GetStringAsync (still within the context).
> 3. GetStringAsync returns an uncompleted Task, indicating the REST request is not complete.
> 4. GetJsonAsync awaits the Task returned by GetStringAsync. The context is captured and will be used to continue running the
>      GetJsonAsync method later. GetJsonAsync returns an uncompleted Task,
>      indicating that the GetJsonAsync method is not complete.
> 5. The top-level method synchronously blocks on the Task returned by GetJsonAsync. This blocks the context thread.
> 6. … Eventually, the REST request will complete. This completes the Task that was returned by GetStringAsync.
> 7. The continuation for GetJsonAsync is now ready to run, and it waits for the context to be available so it can execute in the context.
> 8. Deadlock. The top-level method is blocking the context thread, waiting for GetJsonAsync to complete, and GetJsonAsync is waiting for
>      the context to be free so it can complete.

And the simple available solutions (also from the blog):

> 1. In your “library” async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever possible.
> 2. Don’t block on Tasks; use async all the way down.

The 2nd solution suggests that you change `button1_Click` into:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((await LoginUser(tUser.Text, Password.Text)).IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Notifier.Notify("Successfully logged in.. Please wait!");

    }
    else
    {
        Notifier.Notify("Please check your Credential..");
    }            
}
```