# Why do HTTP requests never return with async await?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am trying to conduct an HTTP call to another server from within an ASP.NET application run on IIS 8.5.

To get started, I took some hints from an article by Microsoft, [*Call a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).
I could easily see a pattern of how they make HTTP calls there; to show just one shortened example:

```
    static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // retrieve response payload
            ... = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<...>();
        }
        // do something with data
    }
```

Easy enough, I thought, so I quickly wrote a similar method for my application (note that the `ReadAsAsync` extension method [appears to require an additional library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399324/where-is-httpcontent-readasasync), so I chose one of the built-in, more abstract, but otherwise presumeably analogous methods):

```
    private async Task<MyInfo> RetrieveMyInfoAsync(String url)
    {
        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyInfo>(responseBody);
    }
```

Unfortunately, calling this method will cause my application to hang. When debugging, it turns out that the `await` call to `GetAsync` never returns.

After searching around for a bit, I stumbled over a [remotely similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033532/getasync-not-returning-httpresponsemessage), in whose comments section I found [a very interesting suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033532/getasync-not-returning-httpresponsemessage#comment59716401_36033532) by [Mr. B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2809478/mr-b):

> Remove all the async stuff and make sure it works.

So I gave it a try:

```
    private Task<MyInfo> RetrieveMyInfoAsync(String url)
    {
        return HttpClient.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(response =>
        {
            response.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }).ContinueWith(str => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyInfo>(str.Result.Result));
    }
```

**Somewhat surprisingly (to me), this works.** `GetAsync` returns the expected response from the other server within less than a second.

Now, working with AngularJS at the same time, I am a bit disappointed by things like `response.Result.Content` and `str.Result.Result`. In AngularJS, I'd expect the above call to be simply something like:

```
$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
});
```

Even if we discount the automatic JSON deserialization that's happening in JavaScript, the AngularJS code is still easier as e.g. `response` is not wrapped into a promise or anything like that, nor will I end up with a structure like `Task<Task<...>>` when returning another promise from within the continuation function.

Therefore, I am not very happy with having to use this `ContinuesWith` syntax rather than the more readable async-await pattern, if the latter just worked.

**What am I doing wrong in the async-await variant of my C# HTTP call?**

Comment: Try doing `await HttpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false)` and tell if it helped.

Comment: Are you using `Wait()`, `Result` or `GetResult()` anywhere?

Comment: @V0ldek: Indeed, that helps. What is happening there?

Comment: Here is a very good explanation by Stephen Cleary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code

Comment: @FCin: In the callstack leading up to my request, beside some `await` calls, I am using `WhenAll` and `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, yes.

Comment: Then `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is causing the deadlock. See my answer for a better explanation.

Comment: very good conversation, I had the same problem, and I got clue from your talks and solved my problem. thanks @V0ldek and O.R.Mapper

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So judging by the fact that `ConfigureAwait(false)` helped with your issue, please, read these from Stephen Cleary's blog:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

The guy's pretty much an `async` expert (he wrote the Concurrency in C# Cookbook book), so whatever I can say he probably explains better. Basically you're blocking the ASP.NET thread somewhere, maybe not using `await` all the way but rather `Wait`, `Result` or `GetResult()`. You should be able to diagnoze the issue yourself using that blog.

What `ConfigureAwait(false)` does is it does not capture the current context, so the HTTP request gets performed (correctly) somewhere else than on the ASP.NET context, preventing a deadlock.

EDIT:

`GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is what's causing the issue, judging by your comment. If you changed that to `await` and the calling method to `async` you'd probably fix everything.

Since C# 7.0 and `async Task Main()` method support there's really no reason to block instead of using `await` in your application code, ever.

Comment: The difference is that the request thread is entered to resume the method when you set ConfigureAwait(false).

Comment: "If you changed that to await and the calling method to async you'd probably fix everything." - I wasn't aware I could just declare an ASP.NET web API controller method as async, but apparently, it works. I am now getting an "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending" exception, but I presume that is unrelated to this particular issue, so I am going to mark this as accepted.

Comment: He didn't pay me for the ad, but if you're interested in `async`/`await` or other concurrency-related C# stuff, then the book I mentioned is a good read.